# How do I submit form data via AJAX to Braintree Transparent redirect?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, braintree

Using Python and JQuery here..

We previously were submitting using a normal `form.submit();` in the `submitHandler` of the validation (JQuery plugin) call.  This was submitted to Braintree's transparent redirect url, with the redirect-to set to be a GET handler on our server.  We do the confirm and then another redirect in our handler.  If the submitted data didn't pass braintree (a bad credit card, say), then we write some html to a `<div id="error">errormessage</div>` in the response from our handler, and this gets inserted in the user's page.

The problem is if there is an error in our handler, which would produce a 500 status code, everything falls to hell and the user's page has undesirable behavior.

I want to be able to handle the 500 response from our handler, if it happens.

I was thinking I could do it using the `statusCode` attribute of jQuery's AJAX.

here's what I've tried (in the `submitHandler`):

```
var data = $(form).serialize();
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: braintree_url,
  data: data,
  statusCode: {
    500: function() {
      alert('broked response yo');
    }
  }
});
```

And then I intentionally raise an error in our handler to force the 500.

But my ajax submit to the Braintree url is not working.  The `form.submit();` worked fine, however.

What am I doing wrong?  Am I wrong to think that a form can be submitted via AJAX like this and produce the same result?

FWIW, we are providing a number of attributes to our html form, as follows:

```
%form#addcard{"action": braintree_url, "method": "post", "autocomplete": "off", "submittype": "secure", "next": braintree_url, "target": "hidden_iframe")}
```

EDIT:

I realized after some more reading about ajax that the probable reason my setup here is not working is because it's calling out to another domain (Braintree's), in violation of the same origin policy.  So the browser is not carrying it out.

from: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

Answer (score 4):

Ok... this is the decade-old version of ajax, but it's working awesomely for me:

Use a normal form submission (no calls to $.ajax), but target a hidden iframe in your page:

```
<form action="<%= Braintree::TransparentRedirect.url %>" method="POST" target="braintree-result">
...
</form>

<iframe name="braintree-result" id="braintree-target" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

Then hook onto the iframe's `load` event with jQuery:

```
$('#braintree-target').on('load', function() {
    var data = $.parseJSON( $(this).contents().text() );
    // Handle response data here
});
```

Then change your braintree callback URL to return JSON data, which will render in your iframe so you can handle it client-side.  That's it! Note that this method assumes you're having braintree redirect back to a URL with the same origin as the current page.  Otherwise I don't think you'll be able to read the iframe contents.

Comment: Are there any security issues using iframe? Even I need to implement transparent redirect using Ajax but I am little worried about using iframes.

Comment: @user2235057 The browser worries about that for you, at great length. It's probably more secure than AJAX, because if Braintree sent you back some malicious code and you tried to execute it, then it could do anything it wanted inside your page. By posting to an iframe, the browser will protect you from accessing anything inside that iframe unless the iframe is pointed at a URL on your own domain, which is what this solution relies on. (After posting to Braintree, they will redirect the iframe back to your specified redirect URL.)